# Emacs can not activate fcitx

Tags: emacs, slackware, fcitx

I can use fcitx normally in all of other programs. But I can't not use fcitx in Emacs which means I can not switch to other input method such as Chinese input method. I tried a lot and Googled a lot didn't find solution. This confuses me a lot!

I use `emacs -q` to start emacs.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

1. Emacs version: 25.1.1
2. fcitx version: 4.2.8.5
3. Operating system: Slackware 14.2

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux Planet 4.4.38 #2 SMP Sun Dec 11 16:18:36 CST 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

`fcitx-diagnose` output: [fcitx-diagnose](http://paste.lisp.org/display/339461)

`~/.xprofile` and `~/.profile` both contain the following:

```
export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
export LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
```

Comment: Please give details of the problem rather than just dumping your config.  E.g. show us what you've done, what you expected to happen, and what happened instead.

Comment: What I expected to happen: I can switch to Chinese input method in Emacs using `C-M SPACE`. Now, I can use this shortcut in all of the other applications to switch between Chinese input method and English. But in Emacs I can't. I have tested a lot such as changing the shortcut to switch method in Fcitx configuration, change `~/.xprofile` and `~/.profile` as the [fcitx wiki](https://fcitx-im.org/wiki/Input_method_related_environment_variables) said. It doesn't work.

Comment: How do you start Emacs?  Can you try `M-: (getenv "XMODIFIERS") RET` to make sure that your Emacs indeed gets the env-vars settings you put into your `~/.profile` (never heard of `~/.xprofile`).

Comment: @Stefan Thanks! I start Emacs using `emacs -q` as I said in the question. I use the GUI version of Emacs. `M-: (getenv "XMODIFIERS") RET` returns `@im=fcitx` which is the same as the value I set in `~/.profile`.

Comment: Then I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug RET` so that Emacs maintainers can take a look at it: it sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 2):

These are a few steps that worked for me:

1. Edit the `/etc/locale.gen` file, uncomment `zh_CN.UTF-8 UTF-8` line.
2. Run `sudo locale-gen`.
3. Make sure the correct fonts are installed. I used manjaro, so I installed
   `xorg-fonts-misc-otb` from `AUR`, the `xorg-fonts-misc` no longer
   provides the required fonts according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fcitx#Emacs. NOTE that needs to reboot after font installation.
4. Start emacs with the command: `LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8 XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx emacs`. Reference: https://fcitx-im.or/wiki/Input_method_related_environment_variables

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered something like this as well. The problem has something to do with locale settings (`LC_CTIME` in your case).

In my case, fcitx stopped working when I set `LC_TIME` for Emacs to `en`. Emacs daemon complained: `Locale not supported by C library. Using the fallback 'C' locale.` I'm not sure if the problem is caused by an invalid / unavailable locale or setting the locale to anything other than default.

Either way, removing your `LC_CTIME` line in your profile files should help.